# How to use pysvn to commit a revision with revision properties ie revprops?

Tags: svn, pysvn

I'm using pysvn 1.9.5-1 and Client.checkin() to commit a revision with revprops.

[pysvn.Client.checkin Documentation](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_checkin)

Here are the 'checkin' arguments according to the documentation...

> checkin( path,
>           log_message,
>           recurse=True,
>           keep_locks=False,
>           depth,
>           keep_changelist,
>           changelists,
>           revprops,
>           commit_as_operations=False,
>           include_file_externals=False,
>           include_dir_externals=False )

However, when I attempt to use 'checkin' with the revprops argument, I get the following error: TypeError: expecting recurse or depth keyword arg

Thanks.

Comment: You can use recurse or depth but not both. I recommend depth for new code.